# How can transform the question into Wolfram language?

Tags: equation-solving

I've been sitting with this question:

A graph has 7 corners. The degree of each corner of the graph is 3 or 4. How many edges does the graph contain if both degrees are represented?

And this is the solution:

[image]

So my question is how I can put what I have on paper to try and solve it in Mathematica?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

number of vert. with degree 3:

```
n3= {2,4,6};
```

number of vert. with degree 4:

```
n4= 7-n3;
```

number of edges = half of sum of vertices times degree:

```
(3 n3+4 n4)/2
(*{13, 12, 11}*)
```